# How to handle Invalid Argument Error in keras

Tags: keras

Getting this error while trying to train the model using keras.

> InvalidArgumentError: indices[48,2] = 5388 is not in [0, 5388)
>   [[Node: embedding_1/embedding_lookup = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32,
>   Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT,
>   _class=["loc:@training/RMSprop/Assign_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read,
>   embedding_1/Cast,
>   training/RMSprop/gradients/embedding_1/embedding_lookup_grad/concat/axis)]]

The actual line is this...

```
model.fit_generator(generator = generate_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size),
                    steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data = generate_batch(X_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size),
                    validation_steps = val_samples//batch_size)
```

> Epoch 1/50  73/237 [========>.....................] - ETA: 32:10 -
>   loss: 7.4517 - acc: 0.1711

And entire code is here...

https://github.com/shantanuo/pandas_examples/blob/master/deep_learn/WordLevelEngMarNMT.ipynb

Code cloned from...
https://github.com/hlamba28/Word-Level-Eng-Mar-NMT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your embedding layer is defined as:

```
# Encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
enc_emb =  Embedding(num_encoder_tokens, latent_dim, mask_zero = True)(encoder_inputs)
```

The token index 0 is considered to be a special value (no input); so you will need to define an Embedding with num_encoder_tokens + 1.

You are adding 1 to num_decoder_tokens already; you need to do the same to num_encoder_tokens.